# Curl is not connecting

Tags: bash, shell, curl, homebrew, deno

Here is me attempting to install homebrew:

```
Password:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
Elijahs-MacBook-Air:~ jah$
```

Here is me trying to install Deno:

```
Elijahs-MacBook-Air:~ jah$ curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
Elijahs-MacBook-Air:~ jah$
```

Comment: Wat is the output of `curl -vfsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh` ? You possibly have an issue with curl too old to support the SSL cypher from this website.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  or [apple.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem running your command (on my `Mojave` machine).

```
$  curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
######################################################################## 100.0%##O#-#                          ######################################################################## 100.0%
Archive:  /Users/rchen/.deno/bin/deno.zip
  inflating: deno
Deno was installed successfully to /Users/rchen/.deno/bin/deno
Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.bash_profile (or similar)
  export DENO_INSTALL="/Users/rchen/.deno"
  export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
Run '/Users/rchen/.deno/bin/deno --help' to get started
```

deno installation check

```
$ /Users/rchen/.deno/bin/deno --help
deno 1.2.3
A secure JavaScript and TypeScript runtime

Docs: https://deno.land/manual
Modules: https://deno.land/std/ https://deno.land/x/
Bugs: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues

To start the REPL:
  deno
...
```

Since you have tagged `homebrew`, can you run `brew config` and `brew doctor` for me? Thanks!